# Float is not recognizing numbers with a "," between it

Tags: ios, decimal, decimal-point, numpad

When using the UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad option, the button in the bottom left will be a ",". But I want a ".", not a ",".
Is it possible to change this?

- Can I add an extra button to the NumberPad?
- Or can I change every "," with a "."?

Answer (score 1):

The decimal keypad shows either a period or a comma depending on the user's locale as set in the Region Format setting in the Settings app (Settings -> General -> International).

You don't want to force a period. Users in locales that expect a comma want to see a comma.

If you need to convert a user-entered number string into a number, use `NSNumberFormatter` to do so. This will properly deal with the user's locale and number format.

Comment: I am using the textField's text to transform to a floatValue and the problem is that decimal numbers won't be registered when using a "," but it will when using a ".".

Comment: That's why I said you need to use an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert the user-entered text into a number value. The number formatter will know how to deal with the comma or period based on the user's locale.

Comment: BTW - your original question is the wrong question. The question should not have been about changing the decimal key on the keypad. Your question should have been about converting such user-entered values into `float` numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys! I have none experience with NSNumberFormatter, how can I adjust it without using storyboard?